# Wondering if the word " leverage" refer to sanctions or pressure in this context

Tags: word-meaning

Mr Yatsenyuk said this was a "historic day", adding: "We want to be a part of the big European family and this is the first tremendous step in order to achieve for Ukraine its ultimate goal, as a full-fledged member."He added that "the best way to contain Russia is to impose real economic leverage".

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that leverage is closer to pressure than sanctions.  Leverage is when you have the power to do something bad, and use the threat of that to get compliance.  If Russia says "Fine, do whatever you want, we don't care", then Europe has no leverage.

Comment: Not necessarily the power to do something bad, though.  You can leverage your skills in plumbing to avoid the cost of bringing in a plumber to fix your sink, for example.  (I suppose that would be bad for the plumber, on the other hand...)

Comment: Hi there.  Unfortunately I can't respond to your thoughtful comment at Parenting so I'm posting it here.  I have outlined specific actions OP can carry out to protect her children and their electronic devices from the ex-partner's salacious browsing habits.  My last sentence was written in response to OP's strong emotional reaction to her ex-partner's ogling while out in public, and salacious browsing.  I was trying to reassure her that (a) there is a way to protect her children's electronic devices from being used for this type of internet browsing; and (b) his browsing habits ...

Comment: ... aren't her fault.  That's what I meant when I said, "Pornography on the internet is a sad fact of modern life. Please don't take it personally."  I didn't mean she should permit him to view pornography on her daughter's computer.  All I meant was what I said, specifically: *Don't take it personally if that is something your ex-partner has done.*  But, as I outlined at the beginning of my answer, OP can (and I think should) take actions to wall her children off from it. // I hope this helps resolve the misunderstanding.  I have a feeling you and I hold similar values, only that one...

Comment: ... of the sentences in my answer may have been misunderstood.